# Questions about expressing each of the following statements in formal language and negating each of them respectively

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, formal-languages

I am trying to express the following statements in formal language and negating each of them.

The following is my attempted solution.

---

**The universe of each statements is the set of real numbers and both $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ denote positive real numbers.**

*Let $a$ be a fixed element of $\mathbb{R}$. For every $\varepsilon$ there exist $\delta$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $|x^{2} - a^{2}| < \varepsilon$.*

*For every $\varepsilon$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $1/n$ < $\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.*

Each of the followings is the expression in formal language for each of the statements respectively:

$\forall \varepsilon,(\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \exists \delta ,(\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \wedge \forall x,(|x-a|<\delta \rightarrow |x^{2} - a^{2}|<\epsilon))).$

$\forall \varepsilon,(\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \exists N,(N\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge \forall n,(n \geq N \rightarrow 1/n < \varepsilon))).$

The respective negation of the each of the statements are the following:

$\exists \varepsilon ,(\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \wedge \forall \delta ,(\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \exists x,(|x-a| < \delta \wedge |x^2 - a^2| \geq \varepsilon))).$

$\exists \varepsilon ,(\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \wedge \forall N,(N \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \exists n,(n \geq N \wedge 1/n \geq \varepsilon))).$

Each of the above negations of the original statements can be expressed as plain English respectively as follows:

*Let a be a fixed element of $\mathbb{R}$. There is a positive real number $\varepsilon$ and for every $\delta$, if $\delta$ is a positive real number, then there exists $x$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|x^2 - a^2| \geq \varepsilon$.*

*There exists a positive real number $\varepsilon$ and for every $N$, if $N$ is an integer, then there exists an $n$ such that $n \geq N$ and $1/n \geq \varepsilon$.*

---

My questions are: Are all my expressions correct , and why in all of the cases, when one negates each of the statements, one does not negate: the definition "Let $a$ be a fixed element of $\mathbb{R}."$, $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, and $N \in \mathbb{Z}$?

All statements are form:

Daepp, U. and Gorkin, P., 2011. Reading, writing, and proving. 2nd ed. New York: Springer, p.46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call these formulations of the statements and their negations correct. The extra subdomain quantifiers you mention could be avoided but you’d get a longer statement and it wouldn’t really affect the negation, in that $\forall \varepsilon \in \Bbb R^+ \phi$would be negated as $\exists \varepsilon \in \Bbb R^+ \lnot \phi$ etc. So leave them in I’d say.

The $a$ is what’s formally called a parameter of the formula; it need not be negated.